# Returning to top of program to try again

Tags: c#

I am teaching myself C# and the current chapter challenge asked me to:

Take your last project and create additional methods that subtract, multiply or divide the two numbers passed into it.  In the divide method, check that the second number is not 0, since dividing by 0 is an illegal mathematical concept.  If the second number is a 0, just return back a 0.

Now I wrote the below which I believe satisfies all the criteria.  I wasn't sure if an IF statement was the best choice but it did work.  I also thought that a SWITCH would have also done the trick.

So first question, would IF or SWITCH have been better?

Second question.  In the ELSE, I give a generic failure message if the user does not select one of the available options, but what I would like to do is if the ELSE is called (Not sure what the correct term is), I want the program to go back to the start and ask the user to try again and display the first Console.Writeline() asking to choose an Operator.  I know this isn't part of the challenge, but it seems like a logical addition to the program and would like to know if this is possible without resorting to anything too complicated.

Thanks in advance!

```
        string whichOp;
        int firstNum, secondNum, result;

        Console.WriteLine("What Operator do you wish to use? [A]dd, [S]ubtract, [M]ultiply or [D]ivide?");

        whichOp = Console.ReadLine();

        whichOp = whichOp.ToLower();

        if (whichOp == "a")
        {
            Console.Write("You chose Addition.  Please choose your first number: ");
            firstNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("You chose the number {0}.  Please choose a second number: ", firstNum);
            secondNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            result = Add(firstNum, secondNum);
            Console.WriteLine("You chose the number {0}.  {1} plus {2} equals {3}.", secondNum, firstNum, secondNum, result);
        }
        else if (whichOp == "s")
        {
            Console.Write("You chose Subtraction.  Please choose your first number: ");
            firstNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("You chose the number {0}.  Please choose a second number: ", firstNum);
            secondNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            result = Sub(firstNum, secondNum);
            Console.WriteLine("You chose the number {0}.  {1} minus {2} equals {3}.", secondNum, firstNum, secondNum, result);
        }
        else if (whichOp == "m")
        {
            Console.Write("You chose Multiplication.  Please choose your first number: ");
            firstNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("You chose the number {0}.  Please choose a second number: ", firstNum);
            secondNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            result = Mult(firstNum, secondNum);
            Console.WriteLine("You chose the number {0}.  {1} times {2} equals {3}.", secondNum, firstNum, secondNum, result);
        }
        else if (whichOp == "d")
        {
            Console.Write("You chose Division.  Please choose your first number: ");
            firstNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("You chose the number {0}.  Please choose a second number: ", firstNum);
            secondNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            result = Div(firstNum, secondNum);
            Console.WriteLine("You chose the number {0}.  {1} divided by {2} equals {3}.", secondNum, firstNum, secondNum, result);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("FAIL!  You did not choose an available option.");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static int Add(int num1, int num2)
    {
        int theAnswer;

        theAnswer = num1 + num2;

        return theAnswer;
    }

    static int Mult(int num1, int num2)
    {
        int theAnswer;

        theAnswer = num1 * num2;

        return theAnswer;
    }

    static int Sub(int num1, int num2)
    {
        int theAnswer;

        theAnswer = num1 - num2;

        return theAnswer;
    }

    static int Div(int num1, int num2)
    {
        int theAnswer;

        if (num2 == 0)
            return 0;

        theAnswer = num1 / num2;

        return theAnswer;
    }
```

EDIT: I took the suggestions of those here and rebuilt the program with SWITCH and WHILE.  Someone also said that because a lot of the code is the same I should be able to reuse it.  I like that idea and will look into how I can do that.

```
        var retry = true;
        while (retry)
        {
            retry = false;

            string whichOp;
            int firstNum, secondNum, result;

            Console.WriteLine("What Operator do you wish to use? [A]dd, [S]ubtract, [M]ultiply or [D]ivide?");

            whichOp = Console.ReadLine();

            whichOp = whichOp.ToLower();

            switch (whichOp)
            {
                case "a":
                    Console.Write("You chose Addition.  Please choose your first number: ");
                    firstNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("You chose the number {0}.  Please choose a second number: ", firstNum);
                    secondNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    result = Add(firstNum, secondNum);
                    Console.WriteLine("You chose the number {0}.  {1} plus {2} equals {3}.", secondNum, firstNum, secondNum, result);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                case "s":
                    Console.Write("You chose Subtraction.  Please choose your first number: ");
                    firstNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("You chose the number {0}.  Please choose a second number: ", firstNum);
                    secondNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    result = Sub(firstNum, secondNum);
                    Console.WriteLine("You chose the number {0}.  {1} minus {2} equals {3}.", secondNum, firstNum, secondNum, result);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                case "m":
                    Console.Write("You chose Multiplication.  Please choose your first number: ");
                    firstNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("You chose the number {0}.  Please choose a second number: ", firstNum);
                    secondNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    result = Mult(firstNum, secondNum);
                    Console.WriteLine("You chose the number {0}.  {1} times {2} equals {3}.", secondNum, firstNum, secondNum, result);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                case "d":
                    Console.Write("You chose Division.  Please choose your first number: ");
                    firstNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("You chose the number {0}.  Please choose a second number: ", firstNum);
                    secondNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    result = Div(firstNum, secondNum);
                    Console.WriteLine("You chose the number {0}.  {1} divided by {2} equals {3}.", secondNum, firstNum, secondNum, result);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry.  {0} is not an available option.  Please try again.", whichOp.ToUpper());
                    retry = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    static int Add(int num1, int num2)
    {
        int theAnswer;

        theAnswer = num1 + num2;

        return theAnswer;
    }

    static int Mult(int num1, int num2)
    {
        int theAnswer;

        theAnswer = num1 * num2;

        return theAnswer;
    }

    static int Sub(int num1, int num2)
    {
        int theAnswer;

        theAnswer = num1 - num2;

        return theAnswer;
    }

    static int Div(int num1, int num2)
    {
        int theAnswer;

        if (num2 == 0)
            return 0;

        theAnswer = num1 / num2;

        return theAnswer;
    }
```

Comment: When was the last time you used a program on your machine that asked you to type A, S or M?  And then told you that you FAILED! if you typed something else?  Why won't you make your program more like the ones you use everyday?

Comment: @HansPassant like a graphical calculator application? That's a bit more advanced for a beginner.

Comment: @HansPassant kind of harsh. This is a great start for a beginning self-starter.

Comment: The calculator was rude to you?  Please share.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst  Exactly.  I know it is ugly and very much a 1990s style program, but it is a beginners C# book which uses Console apps.  I assume it is teaching the fundamentals before going into UIs which pretty much every beginners program book I have seen has always done.

Comment: Of course it is fine to be a beginner at C#.  That doesn't mean you have to be rude to your user.  Why don't you just say "Oops!, don't know what you mean!' and type back the valid commands?

Comment: And if the program was going to be used by someone other than me I would have.  You are right though.  Even in code meant for myself, I should practice proper convention and write it as if I was going to release it.

Comment: @HansPassant maybe I just interpreted your words poorly. Not as harsh sounding anymore :)

Comment: @HansPassant If you think that is rude you should try some of my console applications. Definition restricted to adults only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) switch is often a cleaner way to express this kind of branching. The major limitation of switch is that it only works on compile-time constant values (const variables, literal strings, ints, enums, etc.). In this case, that doesn't seem to be an issue, so switch would probably be a good choice for cleaner, slightly shorter code. In performance-sensitive code (which this is certainly not), a single switch can be faster than a bunch of ifs because the program will test the value and jump straight to the right case rather than testing against each if condition until reaching a match.

(2) an easy way to do this would be to wrap your entire program in a loop:

```
var retry = true;
while (retry)
    retry = false;
    // your program
    else { // or default: if you're going with switch
        ...
        retry = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, every of your blocks does almost the same: Read 2 numbers and apply an operation. You should be able to reuse most of it. Only put the `result = ...` line in the switch.

Comment: @ColeJohnson goto should always be the very last, last resort to control program flow. If you can achieve the control you need with the basic if, while, switch statements without breaking the universe then imho those should be considered before goto

Comment: A loop is more sexier than a goto